# Handling failure of the Send Mail Task in SSIS

Tags: email, ssis, task, send

I have an SSIS package that sends mails for each record within a Foreach Loop Container.  After the e-mail is sent, I add some text to a variable (within a Script Task) saying "Mail sent to customer1@domain.com".

However, I would also like to log when the e-mail **fails**.  I added another script task after the Send Mail Task and changed the constraint to "Failure".  I then changed one of the e-mail addresses to an invalid format (like "abc").  When I run it, it fails on the Send Mail Task, but does not go through my Script Task that has the Failure constraint.  In other words, the whole package stops because of this failure.  I have tried messing around with the FailPackageOnFailure and FailParentOnFailure properties, but I still can't get this to work.

Is there a better way to handle this?  I thought my method was pretty simple, but this is not the expected behaviour (for me, anyway).

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or comments.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you trap the error in the OnError Event Handler for the Send Mail Task?

Comment: Good idea. I added a Script Task to the "OnError" event of my Send Mail task. When I run it with my "bad" e-mail address, the Script Task icon turns green (indicating it was processed). Unfortunately, the Send Mail Task still causes the package to fail. I have FailPackageOnFailure and FailParentOnFailure set to "False" for the Send Mail task. Thanks for the idea, but I am not sure what try next (?)

Comment: Are you able to use a Completion constraint (rather than success or failure) after your Send Mail Task, so that the package continues executing regardless of the success of that particular task?

Comment: That was it!  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  I guess I am just to used to the "Success" constraint, that I haven't been thinking of it properly.   Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same a while ago, i had a problem with variable lock :
i was retrieving the SMTP Credential in some variables (login, password, SSL enabled ...) when the package fail i was trying to send another email using the same variables, but they still locked by the first script task (so it fail).
I hade to get the variables and release them programmatically (try-catch-finally) in the first email script task so i'm sure that ther will be no variable lock in the second.

Hope this help